# Backbone js: Accessing View variables from the template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone js and i have written a piece of code like this;

```
Skymama.Views.UsersIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['users/index'],
  render: function() {  
    var allUsers = new Skymama.Collections.Users();
    allUsers.fetch();   
    this.$el.html( this.template({users: allUsers }) );
    return this;
  },

});
```

How can i access the values of `allUsers` in the template under something like this;

```
<% _.each(users, function(user){ %>

<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch() is an asynchronous method, you should call render after fetch() is finished.

usually you wanna initialize your collection in your view's initialize

```
initialize: function () {
   this.collection = new Skymama.Collections.Users([]);
   this.collection.fetch({reset: true});

   this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
},

render: function () {
    this.$el.html( this.template({users: this.collection }) );
    return this;
}
```

'reset' event will be fired on the collection when fetch() is successful.

you can also do this by attaching `this.render` to fetch as its callback

```
  this.collection.fetch().done(this.render);
```

but you will want to bind render's context to the view if you prefer doing it this way

```
  initialize: function () {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');

      //...
  }
```

Comment: Newer versions of Backbone require the `{reset:true}` option to [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) if you want a `'reset'` event.